# How to know if any contact is updated even when app is killed in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am trying to get the full contact list and saved it in local storage Sqlite DB. Now I want to know when my application is killed or in background and I have updated my contacts like (Delete, Update name etc.) Then how I can identify it in react native that contact is just updated ?

Comment: Do you find any way for same ?

Comment: I have found only one way like when our application is awake or in background using the Appstate we can detect the contact updated list from outside the application.